# Continuity preserved unter expectation? Dominated convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $Z$ be a random variable with $0<Z<\infty, 0<\mathbb{E}[Z]<\infty$ and $Z$ be atom-less, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Z=z)=0$. Further, let $g:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be continuous and strictly decreasing and $w>0$ be continuous. Further
$$g(0)=\infty,\quad g(\infty) = 0.$$ Let $F_{Z}$ denote the continuous cdf of $Z$.

Define 
$$\mathcal{X}(C):=\mathbb{E}\left[Z g\left(C \frac{1}{w(F_{Z}(Z))}Z\right)\right], \quad C>0$$ and assume that $\mathcal{X}(C)<\infty\,\,\forall C\in(0,\infty)$.

I want to show that $\mathcal{X}$ is continuous. I wanted to use dominated convergence and started like this.

By assumptions on the functions $g(\cdot),w(\cdot)$ we have that 
$$g\left(C \frac{1}{w(F_{Z}(Z))}Z\right)$$ 
is continuous and strictly decreasing. Consider the sequence of random variables 
$$\left(Z g\left(C_n (1/w'(F_{Z}(Z)))Z\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
for any sequence $\{C_n\}\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Since $\mathcal{X}(C)<\infty \,\, \forall\, C\in(0,\infty)$, we conclude that the above sequence is uniformly integrable (?? - **missing the correct arguments here** - at least I know that they are all in $L^1(\mathbb{P})$) and thus the dominated convergence theorem implies continuity of $\mathcal{X}(\cdot)$.

I know that dominated convergence can be used to prove the assertion, yet I am unsure how to do it. For example what is the correct majorant? Can someone help?